# MySQL to JSON inconsistent extraction

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mongodb, go

I have a MySQL database with 6 tables and about 2 million rows all together.

I want to migrate all the data into MongoDB.

I decided to do this by converting the SQL tables into JSON and importing it to MongoDB.

I wrote a program in Golang to extract the data and output it as JSON.

This is the main function of the program:

```
func main() {
    // Open a database connection
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/employees")
    checkErr(err)
    // Check if reachable
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Database is unreachable:", err)
    }
    // Populate variables with data
    err = populateVars()
    checkErr(err)
    // Marshal variables into JSON
    binaryJSON, err := json.Marshal(collection)
    checkErr(err)
    // Write JSON to a file
    err = writeStringToFile("/home/user01/Temporary/sql2data.json", string(binaryJSON))
    checkErr(err)
}
```

The problem is that the output is inconsistent.

Every time I run the program, the resulting file has a different size and some random fields are missing.

What could be causing this?

It doesn't seem like it's a problem with the logic of the program since everything executes without errors, and most fields are populated just fine.

Could I be reading the information too fast, so that some things get lost occasionally?

Or is there something else that I'm missing?

**Edit:**

Most of the work happens inside the `populateVars()` function call.

It has multiple blocks of code that execute a given SQL query and populate struct variables according to the schema.

This is one such block:

```
rows, err = db.Query("SELECT emp_no, dept_emp.dept_no, dept_name, from_date, to_date FROM dept_emp JOIN departments ON departments.dept_no = dept_emp.dept_no;")
checkErr(err)
i := 0
for rows.Next() {
    var id int
    var depNumber string
    var depName string
    var fromDate string
    var toDate string
    var position = "Employee"
    err = rows.Scan(&id, &depNumber, &depName, &fromDate, &toDate,)
    // For debugging purposes:
    fmt.Println(id, depNumber, depName, fromDate, toDate, position, i)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for i := range collection {
        if collection[i].ID == id {
            collection[i].Departments = append(collection[i].Departments, Department{DepartmentNumber: depNumber, DepartmentName: depName, FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate, Position: position})
            // For debugging purposes:
            fmt.Println(collection[i].Departments)
        }
    }
    i++
}
```

Here's a GitHub link to the whole program:
https://github.com/dchmie01/mysql_to_json/blob/master/main.go

**Edit 2:**

It seems like the issue has to do with query timeout.

Each query takes about 10 min to execute but at about 6 minutes in, I get this error, and the program stops executing the query:

```
[mysql] 2017/04/29 17:35:16 packets.go:66: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2017/04/29 17:35:16 packets.go:412: busy buffer
2017/04/29 17:35:16 driver: bad connection
```

And in the MySQL log file it says:

```
2017-04-29T16:28:49.975805Z 102 [Note] Aborted connection 102 to db: 'employees' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout writing communication packets)
```

So far I tried playing around with MySQL variables to disable any timeouts that might be present, but no luck.

I think the issue might be with the `mysql` driver for Go.

Comment: You know you can use CSV: [Mysql SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) and [mongoiport --type csv](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

Comment: Not easily, I need to restructure the schema, not just dump all the tables.

Comment: I usually use aggregation for this, and if you do something really complex, I assume the inconsistency may come from there. The code in the question is not sufficient to give any answer on that part.

Comment: Thanks, I added a longer explanation. I'm mostly just appending struct variables to a slice of structs when reading each row.

Comment: Is the size of the `collection` the same as the number of `rows` returned from the query? That is, did you preallocate the collection to a know number of returned rows? And do all of your queries, whose result you use to populate the same `collection` slice, return the same number of rows?

Comment: The collection variable is defined as `var collection []Employee` it's not exactly the same as the number of rows because it has nested structures inside it. But each element inside the collection represents a single document in MongoDB terms.

Comment: Then the `range` over it makes no sense since it's size may be different from the number of rows returned by a given query.

Comment: The reason I'm using `range` is to find the right ID number for each employee. I don't think it matters how long it is.

Comment: Sorry my bad, totally missed the `if` condition.

Comment: Your code has memory leak. `rows` must be closed after you finish reading the records. You also need to close `db`. If you want to dump the record into a file, instead loading ALL data into memory before writing to file, it's better to write it per record i.e. retrieve single `Employee` data and then write it to file.

Comment: You're not checking the `rows.Err()` value. A `for rows.Next() {...` loop can be terminated because of some error, as opposed to getting to the end, which you can retrieve with the `rows.Err()` method, so under each loop check that error before continuing.

Comment: @putu This could be it. I'll test it asap.

Comment: @mkopriva I'll add that too.

Comment: It didn't fix the issue unfortunately . The issue seems to be with query timeout. I updated the post with new details in the `Edit 2:` section.

Comment: Did you try the connection parameters? `db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/employees?readTimeout=15m")` Here it's mentioned in the readme: [read timeout](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#readtimeout)

Comment: Not sure why but I'm getting `unknown unit m‌​ in duration 20m‌​` is it supposed to use a different format?

Comment: @mkopriva's answer contains two zero-width unicode characters between the m and ". See https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/576#issuecomment-298232527

Comment: Can you show us the definition of each table? How is each table related/connected to each other? One to one mapping or one to many? Since you're dealing with many records, you should use `LIMIT` in the query, and if possible, use `JOIN` (depend on table definition).

Comment: There is no much ETL logic in the program to put so much efforts into it. See my answer of how it can be done with standard tools.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good way of doing it. Although I'm pretty sure the problem is a network/mysql problem and not a program logic problem. It just seems that the connection times-out after about 5 minutes of execution because the loop takes about 10 min to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use  [Mysql SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) and [mongoiport --type csv](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) instead.

The only thing that the program does is embedding 1-to-many and many-to-many documents, which can be easily done with aggregation framework.

A step-by step example:

1. export csv from mysql

   ```
   SELECT * from employees INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/employees.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
   SELECT * from salaries INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/salaries.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
   SELECT * from titles INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/titles.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
   SELECT * from departments INTO OUTFILE '/tmp.departments.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
   SELECT * from dept_emp INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/dept_emp.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
   SELECT * from dept_manager INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/dept_manager.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"';
   ```
2. import csv into mongo (define 'field spec' according to your schema, see example for employees field spec)

   ```
   mongoimport -d <dbname> -c tmp_employees -f 'id.int32(),birth.date(2006-01-02),first_name.string(),last_name.string(),gender.string(),hire_date.date(2006-01-02)' --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --file /tmp/employees.csv --drop 
   mongoimport -d <dbname> -c tmp_salaries -f 'field spec' --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --file /tmp/salaries.csv --drop 
   mongoimport -d <dbname> -c tmp_titles -f 'field spec' --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --file /tmp/titles.csv --drop 
   mongoimport -d <dbname> -c tmp_departments -f 'field spec' --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --file /tmp/departments.csv --drop 
   mongoimport -d <dbname> -c tmp_dept_emp -f 'field spec' --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --file /tmp/dept_emp.csv --drop 
   mongoimport -d <dbname> -c tmp_dept_manager -f 'field spec' --columnsHaveTypes --type csv --file /tmp/dept_manager.csv --drop
   ```
3. embed data from mongo shell

   ```
   db.tmp_employees.aggregate([
       // 1-to-many joins
       {$lookup: {
           from: 'tmp_salaries',
           localField: 'id',
           foreignField: 'emp_no',
           as: 'salaries'
       }},
       {$lookup: {
           from: 'tmp_titles',
           localField: 'id',
           foreignField: 'emp_no',
           as: 'titles'
       }},
       // many-to-many joins
       {$lookup: {
           from: 'tmp_dept_emp',
           localField: 'id',
           foreignField: 'emp_no',
           as: 'dept_emp'
       }},
       {$lookup: {
           from: 'tmp_dept_manager',
           localField: 'id',
           foreignField: 'emp_no',
           as: 'dept_manager'
       }},
       {$unwind: { path: '$dept_emp', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
       {$lookup: {
           from: 'tmp_departments',
           localField: 'dept_emp.dept_no',
           foreignField: 'dept_no',
           as: 'dept_emp_deps'
       }},    
       {$unwind: { path: '$dept_emp_deps', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
       {$group: {
           _id: '$_id',
           root: {$first: '$$ROOT'},
           dept_manager: {$first: '$dept_manager'},
           departments_emp: {$push: {
               department_number: '$dept_emp.emp_no',
               department_name: '$dept_emp_deps.dept_name',
               from_date: '$dept_emp.from_date',
               to_date: '$dept_emp.to_date',
               position: '$dept_emp.position'
           }},
       }},
       {$unwind: { path: '$dept_manager', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
       {$lookup: {
           from: 'tmp_departments',
           localField: 'dept_manager.dept_no',
           foreignField: 'dept_no',
           as: 'dept_manager_deps'
       }},    
       {$unwind: { path: '$dept_manager_deps', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }},
       {$group: {
           _id: '$_id',
           root: {$first: '$root'},
           departments_emp: {$first: '$departments_emp'},
           departments_manager: {$push: {
               department_number: '$dept_manager.emp_no',
               department_name: '$dept_manager_deps.dept_name',
               from_date: '$dept_manager.from_date',
               to_date: '$dept_manager.to_date',
               position: '$dept_manager.position'
           }},
       }},
       // combine departments to a single array
       {$project: {
           root: 1,
           departments_all: {$concatArrays: [ "$departments_emp", "$departments_manager" ] }
       }},
       //final reshape
       {$project: {
           id: '$root.id',
           birth_date: '$root.birth_date',
           first_name: '$root.first_name',
           last_name: '$root.last_name',
           gender: '$root.gender',
           hire_date: '$root.hire_date',
           salaries: '$root.salaries',
           titles: '$root.titles',
           departments: {$filter: {
               input: "$departments_all",
               as: "departments",
               cond: { $ne: [ "$$departments", {} ] }}}
       }},
       { $out : "employees" }
   ])
   ```
4. delete imported collections from mongo shell

   ```
   db.tmp_employees.drop();
   db.tmp_salaries.drop();
   db.tmp_titles.drop();
   db.tmp_departments.drop();
   db.tmp_dept_emp.drop();
   db.tmp_dept_manager.drop();
   ```